# I can't get videostream after 5seconds from RTSP video using opencv

Tags: python

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math
import os
from setup import config, load_model
import datetime

os.environ['OPENCV_FFMPEG_CAPTURE_OPTIONS'] = 'rtsp_transport;udp'
video_name = "rtsp://sfkhikvision:Summer2023@192.168.1.230:554/Streaming/Channels/1"
video = cv2.VideoCapture(video_name, cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)

ret, frame = video.read()

            if ret:
                frame_resized = cv2.resize(frame, (416,416)) # resize frame for prediction
            else:
                continue
```

This code generated video (4 seconds).
After generating it, `video.read()` returns "None",
so I can't get video stream for long time.
What is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to continuously read frames from the stream within a loop. Modify your code like the following:

```
os.environ['OPENCV_FFMPEG_CAPTURE_OPTIONS'] = 'rtsp_transport;udp' 

video_name = "rtsp://sfkhikvision:Summer2023@192.168.1.230:554/Streaming/Channels/1" 

video = cv2.VideoCapture(video_name, cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)

# use while-loop here to continuously capture frames
while True:
    ret, frame = video.read()
    if not ret:
        print("Error: Could not read frame")
        break
    frame_resized = cv2.resize(frame, (416,416))
```